# accessing and writing to array from different threads

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multithreading, c++11

I've an simple array of string of character, and I'm trying to access and write to them through different multiple threads. Infact I've fixed size `char[10]` each since I'll always have length of each string < 500. I know if I would access it, without modification in between, from different threads, there's going to be no problem with it.

The problem occurs when I'm writing to those strings from different threads and when I change some string at `arr[2]` from different threads, the results are kind of unpredictable, since threads might be running ahead of one another and output is unpredicatble and often mix of those 2 strings. This is because the strings are composed of multiple characters and different threads are accessing different chars of same string at same time producing a mix of strings.

I've looked into [mutexes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) variables. Mutexes require to lock the variable and then write the string and then unlock it. Would this be a good approach to solving the problem? I tried to understand the atomic approach but it went straight over my mind :/

Another question would be, if the array was composed of real atomic operations like an array of bool, where I would just have to set true or false to each indices, would this problem occur there too? Since there are no multiple characters, the problem shouldn't be there, right?

Comment: Do all the threads need to write to the same global string?  Can you do all the processing and then return a string at the end and combine all of those from all the threads?

Comment: @NathanOliver The array of strings is global since it has to be accessible to all threads. But yes I can return a direct string to it after processing. would that guarantee that strings aren't badly formed?

Comment: "Not multiple characters -> No problem" is a dangerous wrong conclusion. It' much more complicated than that, there are also caching/visibility issues.

Comment: It is all about synchronization.  You need to make sure that multiple threads do not access the same data at the same time if at least one of them writes.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice introduction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem

Comment: `It' much more complicated than that, there are also caching/visibility issues.` Would you mind providing some resources for above issues you stated. Also I went through the wikipedia entry, and it was kind of generic information that didn't helped immensely.

Comment: @NathanOliver even if its an very simple operation such as changing bool values?

Comment: @hg_git Yes.  The standard states *The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior. [ Note: It can be shown that programs that correctly use mutexes and emory_order_-
seq_cst operations*

Comment: That basically boils down to: *It is undefined behavior to have more than one thread access the same object without synchronization when at least one of them is a writer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal proposition would be: Have a mutex for each string, and threads aquiring the mutex for the string they want to write to before they do so.

Compared to having one global mutex for all strings, this allows parallel access to the different strings, so good chance that you get better performance.

Be aware, though, that multiple mutexes always bring the risk of dead locks, if you do not handle them correctly. One way to avoid such would be to implement each thread not holding more than one mutex at a time. Then you are save immediately.

If you ever need more than one mutex in a thread, then a simple strategy to avoid dead locks is always acquiring the mutex in the same order in every thread.

Comment: Thankyou, could you tell a simple example how multiple mutexes can be a problem - `multiple mutexes always bring the risk of dead locks, if you do not handle them correctly`. How would deadlock occur here.

Comment: @hg_git Imagine two threads, T1 and T2, and two mutexes M1 and M2. Both threads want to aquire both mutexes. T1 is running, manages to lock M1, but is interrupted. T2 runs, manages to lock M2, but cannot get M1, because it is already locked. Now running T1 again, cannot get M2 any more because of T2 having locked it. None of both threads running any more...

Comment: @hg_git Problem here is that the mutexes are aquired in different order. If both T1 and T2 would have tried to first lock M1, this would not have occured.